# Is a Chronic Disease Incurable?

Tags: dermatology, disease

One of my friend's toe nails was removed, because of a chronic disease effect on his hands and leg. His doctors told him it's Psoriatic disease and its a type of chronice disease thats incurable. The doctors told him to not get stressed and advised him to take Vitamin D. It's been more than 1 year. Is this chronic disease incurable? If not, how can he cure this?

Comment: There is no treatment that will get rid of psoriasis. What you can do is treat the symptoms to make it more manageable. However, even you can have a normal life you will never be cured.

Comment: Its helpful if anyone provide improved treatment suggestions over the previous treatment.